# Do I have to give priority to a car coming from the right in a "fietsstraat" in Belgium?

Tags: bicycles, belgium, traffic

The other day, I was driving with my bike through a bicycle street (fietsstraat) in Belgium. In these kind of streets, cars cannot overtake the bikes in the street. But when there's a car coming from the right, do I have to give priority to that car or can I just ride along?

Comment: Was the street your were on, or the crossing, indicated as having preference over the side street?

Comment: I don't remember, but I don't think there was an indication. You can literally find nothing about this on the internet. @Willeke

Comment: @AutoDemolisher: I think Willeke was asking about local signage rather than you finding a global rule about your particular intersection. Google Maps Street View might help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the street or crossing does not have an indication that traffic on your street has preference over the side streets, the normal rule of 'yield for traffic from the right' tells you what to do.

Being on a 'fietsstraat' does not give you magical preference over cars if other rules tell that the car should get the right of way.

Besides, as the car can not overtake you on the street farther down, it is good practice to let the car go in front of you even when you would usually get in front of it according to the local rules, (like when they come from the left.) The only exception to that 'gentleman behavior' is as you can see the car will get stuck in traffic a little down the road where you as cyclist can get past that point, but even then you will have to let a car from the right go first.

Comment: Downvoted because I disagree with the so-called "gentleman behavior", which is opinionated.

Comment: @FooBar, you may disagree, I get many a smile and raised fingers in thanks for letting cars in where I have the right to go first, as they can not (or are not allowed to) overtake me farther on. "gentlemanly" is not just male, by the way.

Comment: Downvoter may be annoyed at the genderization of "gentleMANly".